# I can't send any post since yesterday, would you help me, please.

Tags: support

Here, one of my last posts those I was about to send since 2 days but, I couldn't do that and actually, I don't get it why I'm not able to do that:

"
About A Trigonometry Equation:

How could "cos2x" equals "(cos^2*x)-(sin^2*x)"? Could you show me that step by step, please?
"

Comment: I was sending this kind of messages to "Mathematics" section but, I can't any more now, why?

Comment: What happens when you try to post your question?

Comment: It says like "your message is not qualified enough to send this website.". I wonder what's the problem here...

Comment: I've tried even pure HTML 4.x code also but, didn't work at all for me... Should I try it once more right now?

Comment: Please try again and copy the **exact** error message. It is much easier to diagnose your problem if we know exactly what the error message says.

Comment: Sure, will do so right now, sir.

Comment: Again, I'm still not able to post anything more into that section and the server returns this exact message to me:

Oops! Your question couldn't be submitted because:

    It does not meet our quality standards.


That's all. So, any help, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please [read this FAQ item](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92074/what-can-i-do-when-getting-it-does-not-meet-our-quality-standards) on Meta.StackExchange about why this message comes up, and how you can avoid being stopped by it.

Comment: Yes sir. Thank you very much...

Comment: Still, it's not working properly for my client machine... I may try something different later... Some people don't want to see my messages or post around there, maybe that's why... :) But, actually, it would NOT be nice being denied or ignored like that, right... Thank you again...

Comment: It's OK for now, sir. It's working back now so, I feel more satisfied and happy right now... :) Thanks...